# QGIS DBManager Query between Shapefile and PostgreSQL Table

Tags: qgis, dbmanager

I have an instance of DB Manager running and I have TWO connections present in the left pane of the DB manager form.

1. First connection is to a static shapefile on my local file system
2. Second connection is to a PostgreSQL DB-table

I would like to run a compound query between the two in DB Manager.

However, The problem is when you instantiate an SQL window it is either associated with one or another connection. Any suggestions.

Is there a way to perform such a query with in QGIS Manager.

I am running QGIS v2.18.11 and we do not have any shp plugins, availabl e and nor the means to download them

Comment: Have you tried using virtual layers? Using virtual layers you can relate different data sources using SQL. To create the virtual layers the supported query language is SQLite and SpatiaLite.

Comment: I have had limited exposure to QGIS but I will look into how to create virtual layers for both connections

Comment: Maybe this video can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coTSHnWvZXA

Comment: Virtual layers do not exist in QGIS v2.18.11

Comment: Virtual layer exists in version 2.18.11 even from version 2.14 it could be used already.  https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/index.html#feature-virtual-layers

Comment: You should be able to simply load all relevant sources (shp, PG, ...) as layers into the project and query across all of them in the `DB Manager | Tree | Virtual Layers | QGIS Layers` (as all loaded layers in QGIS are a type of virtual layer already).